# Injecting JavaScript(JSNI) to Cell Table DOM

Tags: java, gwt

In my application i am using GWT Cell Table, for some of the Column Header i want to add tooltip.Column Header is created by using SafeHtml and Injecting JS to cell table header using JSNI. But that time the DOM is not creating and JavaScript is not attaching to the column Header for tooltip.If i use Timer then the Problem is goes off,I don't want to use Timer.Is there any Way to inject JS?Any Clue?See below code,

***Column Header SafeHtml:***

```
SafeHtml="<span>Total</span><span title='' rel='tooltipTop' class='reqFull' data-original-title='{0}'> <i class='fa fa-info-circle'></i></span>";
```

***JSNI:***

```
 private static native void initTooltip() /*-{
    $wnd.$(document).ready(function(){
         $wnd.jQuery("[rel=tooltipTop]").tooltip({ placement: 'top'});
    });

    }-*/;
```

I am Calling this JSNI after the table creation but still DOM is not ready.
Even i tried calling this JSNI Script in onAttach() Method,

```
@Override
    protected void onAttach() {
        super.onAttach();
        initTooltip();
        }
```

Any Suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use timer to resolve this Issue,

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                initTooltip();
            }
        });
```

Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I think the [Scheduler](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleDeferred(com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.ScheduledCommand)) may also be a solution. It will add the jsni to the start of the next JavaScript loop.

But I think there still may be a better solution instead of using Timer or Scheduler.

**update**

There seems to be an error in your code:

In JSNI the `document` needs to be calles as `$doc`

```
private static native void initTooltip() /*-{
    $wnd.$($doc).ready(function(){
        $wnd.jQuery("[rel=tooltipTop]").tooltip({ placement: 'top'});
    });
}-*/;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.I dont want to use Timer which will hit performance ,Is there any other approach?